# Copy constructor not called in templated class

Tags: c++, g++, copy-constructor

I have the following class in file `myclass.hpp`:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_HPP
#define MYCLASS_HPP
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
template <std::size_t l, typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass();
  MyClass(const MyClass<l,T>& other);
};
#include "myclass.tpp"
#endif
```

And the pseudo implementation file `myclass.tpp`:

```
template <std::size_t l, typename T>
MyClass<l,T>::MyCLass() {
  std::cout << "Ctor" << std::endl;
}
template <std::size_t l, typename T>
MyClass<l,T>::MyCLass(const MyCLass<l,T>& other) {
  std::cout << "COPY Ctor" << std::endl;
}
```

In my main file I have:

```
#include "myclass.hpp"
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  MyCLass<10,int> m1;
  MyClass<10,int> m2;
  m1 = m2; // <-- HERE
}
```

The copy constructor is not called. The printout is the following:

> Ctor
>
> Ctor

What am I doing wrong? Thankyou

Comment: It should not be called. Try defining `assignment operator` and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you aren't calling a copy constructor, you're calling a copy assignment operator. A copy constructor call would be:

```
MyClass<10,int> m2(m1);
```

The function you're calling has the signature:

```
template <std::size_t l, typename T>
MyClass<l, T>& operator=(const MyClass<l, T>& other);
```

Answer (score 1):

An [implicitly defined assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator#Implicitly-defined_copy_assignment_operator) is called instead. It performs memberwise assignment (that is, effectively nothing in this case), and so no copy-ctor is invoked.
Try this instead:

```
MyCLass<10,int> m1;
MyClass<10,int> m2 = m1;
```